# YTPlayerView: Remove Share Button in top right corner

Tags: ios, youtube-api, ytplayerview, ytplayer

I'm using `YTPlayerView` from the youtube-ios-player-helper library for video playback, but want to hide the share button in the top right corner that comes with it - anyone have a solution?

I've circled what I'm talking about here:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by passing these parameters:

```
let playerVars = [
  "modestbranding": 1,
  "showinfo": 0
]
playerView.loadWithVideoId(video.id, playerVars: playerVars)
```

Comment: Hi! How did you hide the YouTube logo that appears in the bottom right corner? And also is it possible to change the play icon?

Comment: You cannot hide the YouTube icon, but you can prevent it from being pressed by placing a transparent view over it. Don't think you can change the play button.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS platform, just pass **showinfo** parameter to 0 before load the video:

```
NSDictionary *paramDic = @{
        @"showinfo": @0
    };

[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"M7lc1UVf-VE" playerVars:paramDic];
```